# JComboBox muestra datos null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, combobox, map

Mi pregunta es porque mi `JComboBox` me muestra esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en que lo cargo es:

```
public DefaultComboBoxModel cargarClientes() {
        this.iniciarTransacciones();
        this.query = this.session.createQuery("SELECT c.clientesidCliente, c.nombreApellido FROM Clientes as c");
        //La consulta devuelve un array de objetos, lo almacenamos en la lista object[]
        List<Object[]> listaClientes = this.query.list();
        Map<Short, String> mapaClientes = new TreeMap<>();
        this.transaction.commit();
        this.session.close();

        DefaultComboBoxModel<Clientes> modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++) {
            //Cargamos los datos al mapa
            mapaClientes.put((Short)listaClientes.get(i)[0], (String)listaClientes.get(i)[1]);
        }

        //Regorremos el mapa
        for (Map.Entry<Short, String> clienteEntry : mapaClientes.entrySet()) {
            if (clienteEntry.getKey() != null && clienteEntry.getValue() != null) {
                //Agregamos al modelo los datos de los clientes (idcliente, nombreCliente)
                modeloCombo.addElement(new Clientes(clienteEntry.getKey(), clienteEntry.getValue()));
            }
        }

        return modeloCombo;
    }
```

Dentro del JFrame donde se encuentra el JComboBox hago:

```
private void cargarClientes() {
        try {
            DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCliente = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            modeloCliente = transaccionesControlIngresosDiario.cargarClientes();
            JcboClientes.setModel(modeloCliente);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Mi clase Clientes:

```
public class Clientes implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Short clientesidCliente;
    private Localidad localidad;
    private String nombreApellido;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    private Byte sexo;
    private Date fechaIngreso;
    private String objetivos;
    private float pesoInicial;
    private String lecturaCorporal;
    private Set ejercicioses = new HashSet(0);
    private Set controlingresosdiarios = new HashSet(0);
    private Set cobranzas = new HashSet(0);


    public Clientes() {
    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR QUE UTILIZO PARA LLENAR DefaultComboBoxModel
    public Clientes(Short clientesidCliente, String nombreApellido) {
        this.clientesidCliente = clientesidCliente;
        this.nombreApellido = nombreApellido;
    }

    public Short getClientesidCliente() {
        return this.clientesidCliente;
    }

    public void setClientesidCliente(Short clientesidCliente) {
        this.clientesidCliente = clientesidCliente;
    }

    public Localidad getLocalidad() {
        return this.localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(Localidad localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getNombreApellido() {
        return this.nombreApellido;
    }

    public void setNombreApellido(String nombreApellido) {
        this.nombreApellido = nombreApellido;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return this.fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }



    //Resto de los gatter and setters



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombreApellido + " " + fechaNacimiento + " " + sexo + " " + fechaIngreso + " " + objetivos + " " + pesoInicial + " " + lecturaCorporal + " " + localidad;
    }
}
```

Estoy utilizando **hibernate 4.3.1.Final**, espero que puedan ayudarme con alguna pista de lo que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si únicamente deseas mostrar en tu `JComboBox` el valor de `nombreApellido` de cada objeto es, modifica el método `toString()` de esta forma:

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombreApellido;
    }
```

De esta forma al cargar los objeto `Cliente` en tu `JComboBox`,

```
    DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCliente = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    modeloCliente = transaccionesControlIngresosDiario.cargarClientes();
    JcboClientes.setModel(modeloCliente);
```

únicamente se mostrará el valor de `nombreApellido`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me explique bien yo, lo siesto! Lo que yo **solo** quiero mostrar es el campo **nombreApellido** nomas para que se vea en el JComboBox solamente el nombre y el apellido pero **no **  los  **null**, el campo **Clienteidcliente** tambien lo necesito para poder almacenar el **id** en la bbdd, por ese motivo utilizo el constructor de dos parametros.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, modifica el método toString(), saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Casi me volvi loco buscando la solución y era una pavada! Funciona perfecto.

Comment: Me da gusto funcione correctamente @GerardoFerreyra saludos!